# Emmet in Chrome devtools' sources tab?

Tags: html, workflow, google-chrome-devtools, text-editor, emmet

Is it possible to get [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) in Chrome devtools' sources tab? I recently started using [workspaces](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/#toc-workspaces) in devtools, so now I can edit HTML files in the sources tab in addition to CSS and JS. Emmet would make this even better.

Answer (score 0):

Not really... not without some work.  If you are just drooling to get this done, here is Google's support page for extending their DevTools:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools

What is your IDE?  Emmet comes with installation bundles for Notepad++, Dreamweaver, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to Emmet Livestyle? Dev-tools Workspaces' "resource mapping" mimics Livestyle's bi-directional functionality. It's either/or, you don't need both.

Comment: I think he meant http://emmet.io/

Which is a text expander. I do not know of a way to get that to work in devtools. I wish I did.